# Equality of F# record Types when consumed from C#

Tags: c#, .net, f#

I have the following record type in an F# lib:

```
type Rating = {
        Id : string
        AverageRating : decimal
        ValueRange : int
        Label : string }
```

And as expected, the following test passes in an F# test lib:

```
[Fact]
let ``ShouldConsiderTwoInstancesOfAClassToBeTheSame`` () =

    let a = {Rating.Id = "id"
             AverageRating = 4.3m
             ValueRange = 10
             Label = "label"}

    let b = {Rating.Id = "id"
             AverageRating = 4.3m
             ValueRange = 10
             Label = "label"}

    a = b |> should equal true
    a.Equals b |> should equal true
    a <> b |> should equal false
    System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b) |> should equal false
```

However, the following test in C# fails...both of the first 2 assertions fail, though the third assertion passes fine:

```
    [Test]
    public void ShouldConsiderTwoInstancesOfAClassToBeTheSame()
    {
        var a = new Rating("id", 4.3m, 10, "label");
        var b = new Rating("id", 4.3m, 10, "label");

        Assert.True(a == b);
        Assert.False(a != b);
        Assert.True(a.Equals(b));
        Assert.False(ReferenceEquals(a, b));
    }
```

Is there a way to get the structural equality that record types provide out of the box when consuming from C# using just the operators, or do you need to call Equals() ?

Comment: I don't think C# can grok this (although there are rumours about Record types in C# 9.  In the meantime, [Language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) provides full Record types with structural equality (and loads of other great stuff) in C#, should you need them.

Comment: My first guess would be that F# doesn't work the same way C# does. In your C# code you try to see if `a` equals `b` when they are two different objects, so this cannot be true since they have two different references. That being said I've only used F# so much and I don't know how references or 'objects' are handled.

Comment: What does the IL look like? Looking at https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fsharp-decompiled/ it seems the operators aren't overloaded..

Comment: @CraftyFella that was my next move actually :) cheers

Comment: @DaveCook equality is provided by .NET itself. F# [generates](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgPg9gDgUwHYAIDKBPCAXBBbAWAChjsNEUAlAQ2wEskBzFAXhQG9iVufuBJACYoQKHACcGjLrx4BBAG4Ix1Rghr0mwlAIQBjOnmrBpMlADUjAVzXUmCLQ2wmZAGWoAjBMC3jJKAL68QA==)  custom equality operators. `Equals` should just work

Comment: This is a common gotcha when I try to educate C# devs on F#. The only reasoning I can grok is that the stance is C# is reference equality by default (as a language, not specific to this interop), therefore that is retained. However Equals "does the right thing"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In idiomatic C#, reference types are not expected to test positive for structural equality. `IEquatable` as a contract makes more semantic sense.

Equality, by default, means *equality of reference*. F# is quite different in this regard - it uses *structural equality* for comparisons.
If you look at what F# does for `a = b`, it calls

```
a.Equals(b, GenericEqualityComparer);
```

However, for a type with an `==` operator implemented,  the C# compiler knows to pick the operator's method.

```
push.0 //ldloc, ldfld, etc.
push.1
call bool Rating::op_Equality(valuetype Rating, valuetype Rating)
```

What generally happens for `a == b`, is:

```
push.0
push.1
ceq
```

[ceq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ceq?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks) is much faster than any of the method call alternatives, and is the default equality comparison, which gives you equality of reference.

Other core .NET types may not explicitly implement `==` and `!=`, but the JIT has specific implementation details to perform equality comparison for those intrinsic types (signed, fp, etc.), so they still equate correctly.

If an `==` comparison is semantically important to you, you can implement the operators yourself:

```
type Rating = {
    Id : string
    AverageRating : decimal
    ValueRange : int
    Label : string 
} with
    static member op_Equality (a: Rating, b: Rating) =
      a.Equals b
    static member op_Inequality (a: Rating, b: Rating) =
          not (a.Equals b)
```

And your tests should work again.

Comment: Cheers. This worked a charm and has given me a better understanding of how F# and C# work together

Comment: @DaveCook Comments like yours make it all worth it. :)

Answer (score 1):

In order for `==` to work in C#, the class in question needs to implement the == operator

```
bool operator ==(Rating a, Rating b) => ...
```

If you look at the generated IL-Code for Rating, you will see that it implement `IEquatable<T>, IComparable<T>, GetHashCode()`, etc. but I have seen no operator implementation.